# Totally Ordered Set successor and predecessor unique

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-writing

I'm trying to prove that, in a totally ordered set, an element can have at most one successor and at most one predecessor.

I know that if $x < y$ and there is no $z\in X$ with $x < z < y$ then $x$ is a predecessor of $y$ and $y$ is a successor of $x$.

I know that the successor and predecessor are unique but don't know how to establish it in a proof. Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that the characterizations that you gave of successor and predecessor are *definitions*. In particular this means:

- $x$ is a predecessor of $y$ if *and only if* $x<y$ and there is no $z$ such that $x<z<y.$
- $y$ is a successor of $x$ if *and only if* $x<y$ and there is no $z$ such that $x<z<y.$

So, suppose (for example) that $y_1,y_2$ are successors of $x.$ Since $y_1$ is a successor of $x,$ then $x<y_1,$ and there is no $z$ such that $x<z<y_1.$ In particular, we cannot have $x<y_2<y_1.$ Likewise, $x<y_2,$ and there is no $z$ such that $x<z<y_2.$ In particular, we cannot have $x<y_1<y_2.$ Since $x<y_2,$ but we can't have $x<y_2<y_1,$ it follows that we can't have $y_2<y_1.$ Similarly, we can't have $y_1<y_2.$ From this, we can conclude (why?) that $y_1=y_2,$ which shows that $x$ has at most one successor (since if it has any successors, then they are all equal).

As similar proof approach works for uniqueness of predecessors (if they exist).

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Suppose $y$ and $y'$ are two successors for $x$. Now which is the case: $y<y'$ or $y'<y$?

Comment: I don't exactly know where to take this so could you explain a little further please. Will I ultimately discover that y must equal y'?

Answer (score 0):

It is impossible to have two distinct successors to a point $x \in X$.

Assume, to the contrary, that we have two distinct successors $y_1$ and $y_2$ for a point $x \in X$. We know that the subset $\{x,y_1,y_2\}$ of $X$ can be naturally viewed as a totally ordered structure and it is easy to see that both $y_1$ and $y_2$ must continue being successors to $x$ in this 3 point space. Since $x$ is first, there are only two ways of totally ordering the finite subset:

$\tag 1 x \lt  y_1 \lt  y_2 $
$\tag 2 x \lt  y_2 \lt y_1 $

But if (1) is true then $y_2$ can't be a successor, and if (2) is true then $y_1$ can't be a successor. This is a contradiction.

In a similar manner it can be shown that predecessors must be unique.